# Java UTF-8 to ASCII conversion with supplements

Tags: java, character-encoding, special-characters

we are accepting all sorts of national characters in UTF-8 string on the input, and we need to convert them to ASCII string on the output for some legacy use. (we don't accept Chinese and Japanese chars, only European languages)

We have a small utility to get rid of all the diacritics:

```
public static final String toBaseCharacters(final String sText) {
    if (sText == null || sText.length() == 0)
        return sText;

    final char[] chars = sText.toCharArray();
    final int iSize = chars.length;
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(iSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++) {
        String sLetter = new String(new char[] { chars[i] });
        sLetter = Normalizer.normalize(sLetter, Normalizer.Form.NFC);

        try {
            byte[] bLetter = sLetter.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sb.append((char) bLetter[0]);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The question is how to replace all the german sharp s (ß, Đ, đ) and other characters that get through the above normalization method, with their supplements (in case of ß, supplement would probably be "ss" and in case od Đ supplement would be either "D" or "Dj").

Is there some simple way to do it, without million of .replaceAll() calls?

So for example: Đonardan = Djonardan, Blaß = Blass  and so on.

We can replace all "problematic" chars with empty space, but would like to avoid this to make the output as similar to the input as possible.

Thank you for your answers,

Bozo

Comment: Note that there is no unique mapping: In German, "ö" is replaced by "oe", whereas in Swedish, "ö" is replaced by "o".

Comment: You will need to have this function take in a language parameter and possibly have a default language. Or spend some time trying to work out a way of deciding what language the string would have come from, but that will brake if the string is not long enough. either way, looks like you will need a look up table of some sorts. Let your app go through the entire string, checking each characters and finding what it should be swapped with.

Comment: Another option might be replacing "ö" with "o:" as a sort of "poor man's diacritic".

Comment: Well I'm sure ö can be oe or o, but I would settle with any option. How to get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some simple way to do it, without million of .replaceAll() calls?

If you just support European, Latin-based languages, around 100 should be enough; that's definitely doable: Grab the [Unicode charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) for [Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) and [Latin Extended-A](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0100.pdf) and get the `String.replace` party started. :-)

Comment: I cannot believe that no one did this, made a few maps and said, here is one for people who prefer it this or that way, extend it if you wish some modifications per your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [ICU4J](http://site.icu-project.org/). It includes the `com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator` class, which apparently can do what you are looking for.

Comment: Except that the ICU4J transliterators I've tried are extremely inaccurate (latin, cyrillic and hangul), which exact transliterator do you think would fulfill the original request? I am not able to find anything apparently suitable.

Comment: I've tried ICU4J and it was so complicated that I couldn't even run it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using something like this:

```
Transliterator transliterator = Transliterator.getInstance("Any-Latin; Upper; Lower; NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; NFC", Transliterator.FORWARD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my converter which uses lucene...

```
private final KeywordTokenizer keywordTokenizer = new KeywordTokenizer(new StringReader(""));
private final ASCIIFoldingFilter asciiFoldingFilter = new ASCIIFoldingFilter(keywordTokenizer);
private final TermAttribute termAttribute = (TermAttribute) asciiFoldingFilter.getAttribute(TermAttribute.class);

public String process(String line)
{
    if (line != null)
    {
        try
        {
            keywordTokenizer.reset(new StringReader(line));
            if (asciiFoldingFilter.incrementToken())
            {
                return termAttribute.term();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            logger.warn("Failed to parse: " + line, e);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```